Basic confusion about evolution of wave function of a free particle
I am going through Griffith's introduction to quantum mechanics. An example for a free particle is given where
$$\Psi(x,0) = \begin {cases}A \quad \text{if } x\in [-a,a]\\ 0\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
It follows the schroedinger equation with no potential:
$$\frac {\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=\frac {i h}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2}$$
By the following argument I expected the answer to be that it stays constant over time:
Since the second derivative w.r.t. $x$ is everywhere-zero except at $-a$ and $a$, where it is undefined, so the first derivative w.r.t. $t$ is everywhere-zero except at $-a$ and $a$. Therefore the wave-function has to stay constant over time, except at $-a$ and $a$, where I'm not sure what happens.
Yet if you do a fourier transform, it  gives you a wave function
$$\Psi(x,t)=c\int k^{-1}sin(ka)e^{i(kx-\frac {hk^2}{2m}t}$$
Which when evaluated numerically apparently dissipates into an approximately normal distribution.
What explains this disparity, mathematically? Is it purely because we are doing a numerical approximation? (i.e. if we would do the numerical approximation with "infinite precision" would it in fact be a constant function?) Or is the fourier transform inaccurate for non-smooth wave function? Or is my argument just wrong?

Note that the sharp edges at $-a$ and $+a$ imply an infinite potential jump. i.e. your "free particle" wavefunction is actually in direct conflict with Schrödinger's equation

You only know $\Psi$ at $t=0,$ so you only know "$\partial^2\Psi/\partial x^2$ and $\partial\Psi/\partial t$ are zero for all $x$ except $x=\pm a$" at $t=0.$ This is not enough to deduce that $\Psi(x,t)=\Psi(x,0)$ for any $x$ and $t>0.$ (E.g. the function $f(t)=t^2$ has $\partial f/\partial t=0$ at $t=0$ and yet, for all $t>0,$ $f(t)\neq f(0).$) The derivative of a function at a single point conveys no information about its value at any other single point.
Note that your wavefunction is a bit unphysical. You see that in momentum space, the wavefunction falls off as $k^{-1}.$ As a result, the expected energy of the state is infinite. Also, (but less of a problem) given that there are contributions from all $k$ up to infinity, the disturbance in $\Psi$ will propagate throughout all of space instantly ($\Psi(x,t)\neq\Psi(x,0)$ for all $x$ and $t>0$).
Ignoring these problems of physical interpretation, one way to analytically understand the solution to the Schrodinger equation in this case is to use the propagator of the free particle: $$K(\Delta x,\Delta t)=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar\Delta t}}\exp\left(\!-\frac{m\Delta x^2}{2i\hbar\Delta t}\right),$$ which is the amplitude $\langle x+\Delta x|e^{-i\hat H\Delta t/\hbar}|x\rangle$ for a localized particle to travel a distance $\Delta x$ in a time $\Delta t.$ Note that for a given $\delta t,$ this propagator has a Gaussian shape that spreads out for larger $\Delta t.$ The propagator is useful since the evolution of any initial state $\Psi(x,0)$ is given just by convolving (i.e. "smearing") the initial state with the propagator $$\Psi(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x-x',t)\Psi(x',0)\,dx'.$$ (Note that this shows there's no hope of an elementary closed form solution to your problem. At the same time, it's clear there is a relatively easy expression in terms of a partial Gaussian integral/the error function) As you look at greater and greater $t,$ the width of the propagator $K(\Delta x,t)$ increases. Relative to this width, the initial state looks more and more like it's localized at a point (i.e. more like a Dirac delta distribution). Thus, after the convolution, the final state approaches a Gaussian wavepacket.

Your first reasoning is wrong, the constant part doesn't remain constant. Because from the points $-a$ and $a$ there will be changes propagating in the left and right direction. And the higher frequencies propagate very fast (propagation is not bound by the speed of light in the non-relativistic Schroedinger equation). So immediately after the start the flat part is gone...
